# A simple question regarding differentiating under an integral sign

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

How to prove

$(F(\rho^*+(1+\rho^*)\epsilon))>F(\rho^*)(1+\epsilon)$

is only satisfied when

$\frac{(1+\rho^*)f(\rho^*)}{F(\rho^*)}>1$ ?

How is Leibnitz's rule applied here?
Is it possible to show the full derivation for me ?

Comment: What is $F$? Where is the integral?

Comment: F is the CDF. I suppose I need to use Leibnitz's, but I am not sure.

Comment: Do you want to prove that if the first inequality holds for all $\epsilon>0$ then the second inequality holds?

Comment: I am trying to understand, how can the first inequality holds IFF the second inequality is true. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equality can be written as

$$F(\rho^*+(1+\rho^*)\epsilon)-F(p^*)>\epsilon F(\rho^*)$$

So, if $1+p^*>0$ and the inequality holds for all $\epsilon>0$ then

$$\frac{F(\rho^*+(1+\rho^*)\epsilon)-F(\rho^*)}{(1+p^*)\epsilon}>\frac{F(\rho^*)}{1+p^*}$$

Taking the limit (and using the limit inequality theorem):

$$\lim_{(1+p^*)\epsilon\to 0}\frac{F(\rho^*+(1+\rho^*)\epsilon)-F(\rho^*)}{(1+p^*)\epsilon}\geq \frac{F(\rho^*)}{1+p^*}$$

The thing on the left hand side is $f(p^*)$, so we get

$$f(p^*)\geq \frac{F(\rho^*)}{1+p^*}$$

(which is not quite what you wanted to show).

Comment: Everything is great except the first step, how can you just divide $1+\rho^*$ and cancel $ 1+\epsilon^*$ in the numerator for the RHS

Comment: See the extra step I have added to my answer

Comment: Thanks ! I am so dumb ! You are really helpful !